# DeleteByQuery using NEST and ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having a little difficulty getting NEST's DeleteByQuery method to work.

Very simply the query never finds anything to delete, and I can't figure out why.  I'm using the same query to return records (using Search) and everything works as expected.

```
    private void Delete(MyClass someObject)
    {
        var response = elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<MyClass>(q => q                
            .Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Guid).Equals(someObject.Guid))            
            );
    }
```

I've only just started using NEST, so I'm sure this is a pretty simple problem and I'm just being a little dim!

Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.Equals()` is a .NET method on `Object` that checks for equality.

If you change the call to `Equals()` to `Query(someObject.Guid)` it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I must be missing something because I can't swap out the call to Equals() to Query(someObject.Guid).

Any chance you could give a quick example clarifying what you mean?

Comment: I think in the nuget version its still called QueryString()

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE `NEST` to  version `6.4.0`

```
var response = _client.DeleteByQuery<MyClass>(q => q
            .Query(rq => rq
                .Match(m => m
                .Field(f => f.Guid)
                .Query(guid.ToString())) 
            )
            .Index("Index_Name")
        );
```

Comment: I thought I'd post the following adjustment to specify the index for good Abstraction practise;             var response = _elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<DocumentData>(q => q
            .Query(rq => rq
                .Match(m => m
                .Field(f => f.DocumentID)
                .Query(documentID.ToString()
                ))
            ).Index(indexName)
        );