# Nest DeleteByQuery without the Object name

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to send a Nest delete request to elasticsearch without specifying the object which I don't have. I've seen solutions like:

```
var response = elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<MyClass>(q => q                
            .Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Guid).Equals(someObject.Guid))            
            );
```

From: [DeleteByQuery using NEST and ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475698/deletebyquery-using-nest-and-elasticsearch)

As I'm just reading plain text from a queue I don't have access to the MyClass object to use with the delete request. Basically I just want to delete all documents in an index (whose name I know) where a variable matches for example ordId = 1234. Something like:

```
    var response = client.DeleteByQuery<string>( q => q
        .Index(indexName)
        .AllTypes()
        .Routing(route)
        .Query(rq => rq
            .Term("orgId", "1234"))
    );
```

I see that the nest IElasticClient interface does have a DeleteByQuery method that doesn't require the mapping object but just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just specify `object` as the document type `T` for `DeleteByQuery<T>` - just be sure to explicitly provide the index name and type name to target in this case. `T` is used to provide strongly type access within the body of the request only. For example,

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var deleteByQueryResponse = client.DeleteByQuery<object>(d => d
    .Index("index-name")
    .Type("type-name")
    .Query(q => q
        .Term("orgId", "1234")
    )
);
```

Will generate the following query

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index-name/type-name/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "orgId": {
        "value": "1234"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `_delete_by_query` with `_search` in the URI first, to ensure you're targeting the expected documents :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed reply. You mentioned explicitly mentioning the  index name and type name, if I want to target all document types that match the field can I use .AllTypes() instead of .Type("type-name").

Comment: @CorribView yes you can :)